# Is there a metric for counting AND classification simultaneously?

Tags: loss-function, object-detection, metric

I'm working on a project that mixes object detection and crowd counting.

The metric for object detection is mAP, which combines the regression of the bounding boxes with the precision of the classification. The metrics for crowd counting are MAE and MSE, a regression problem.

The problem I want to solve involves counting and classifying objects in an image. I don't want the precise location of the bounding boxes, hence mAP is not useful, and I need to account for the classification errors, then MAE and MSE are out.

Is there a meric/loss that combines counting and classification?